# Meteor: Auto-update across browsers fails in my app when "space" character is used

Tags: meteor

Here's a strange thing. I'm up and running on my first Meteor app.

You can see it at: http://www.howli.st

Here's what's happening:

1. Press process to use the sample data to take you to the data
   entry screen where you can pop in a few values
2. Take the Session Reference from the top right corner and in another browser open up
   howli.st again and then paste that session reference into the box on
   the right to "retrieve data"
3. Both browsers are now in the same session and if you type data in one it will update in the other.

Small glitch: here's what happens over a series of changes to the form binding box:

1. "hello" -> "hello"
2. "hello world" -> "hello" **note no change in other broswer**
3. "helloworld" -> "helloworld" **the other browser now updates!**

Here's the code from my app:

html:

```
    <tr>
       <td>form binding</td>
       {{#each sessioninfo}}
       <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="formbinding" value={{formbind}} ></td
       {{/each}}    
    </tr>
```

js:

```
Template.thedata.events = {    
 'keyup #formbinding':function(){
     //save formbinding to MyItems
     var thisSession = Session.get("thisSession");
     MySessions.update({_id: thisSession}, {$set : { formbind : $('#formbinding').val()}});
  }
};

Template.thedata.sessioninfo = function(){
    return MySessions.find({}); 
};
```

Any help gratefully received.

**Update** If I use a variable theformbind = $('#formbinding').val() to pass to my update statement then the other browser does update, but it only shows the text preceding the space i.e.

1. abcd -> abcd
2. ab cd -> ab

Looking in the mongodb the correct value "ab cd" has been stored

Comment: Thanks Tom - and thanks for your previous help on the irc chat. I will register an issue on github.

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o_O

Upon a second look I now see that

```
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="formbinding" value={{formbind}} ></td>
```

has no `"` around the formbind, thus you would want it to be

```
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="formbinding" value="{{formbind}}"></td>
```

such that it allows for stuff that contains spaces (and not make new arguments of them).